# декоратор @permission_required выдате ошибку AttributeError: object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь через декоратор `@permission_required` сделать для пользователя ограничения на просмотр модели. То есть в админке убрал в правах пользователя поле `storehouse | Форма | Can view Форма`

но выдает ошибку `'StorehouseHomeView' object has no attribute 'user'`

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

    class StorehouseHomeView(ListView):
        model = Storehouses
        template_name = 'storehouse/storehouse_list.html'
        context_object_name = 'storehouse'
    
        @permission_required('storehouse.view', raise_exception=True)
        def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните саму вьюху в декоратор вот таким образом:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

class StorehouseHomeView(ListView):
    model = Storehouses
    template_name = 'storehouse/storehouse_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'storehouse'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

storehouse_home_view = permission_required('storehouse.view', raise_exception=True)(StoreHouseHomeView.as_view())
```

И используйте `storehouse_home_view` в урлах.

Данная ошибка Вам говорит о том, что декоратору `permissions_required` необходим `request`, которого нет в функции `get_context_data`. А если нет запроса – нет и данных о пользователе.

Вот [ссылка](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf) на офф. документацию по поводу декорирования классовых вьюх.